# Android7.0 MACアドレスの取得

Tags: android, java

Android7.0でMACアドレスの取得方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。
下記はMACアドレスを取得しようとしているコードです。

```
String MacAddress = "";
DevicePolicyManager dpm = (DevicePolicyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, AdminReceiver.class);
if (dpm.isAdminActive(cn)) {
    MacAddress = dpm.getWifiMacAddress(cn);
    Log.d("","MacAddress:"+MacAddress);
}else{
    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, cn);
    intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "");
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

AdminReceiver.java

```
public class AdminReceiver extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onEnabled(context, intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onDisabled(context, intent);
    }
}
```

admin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-policies>
        <limit-password />
        <watch-login />
        <reset-password />
        <force-lock />
        <wipe-data />
        <expire-password />
        <encrypted-storage />
        <disable-camera />
        <disable-keyguard-features />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
    android:name=".AdminReceiver"
    android:description="@string/admin_description"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.device_admin"
        android:resource="@xml/admin" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: 参考 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33159224/getting-mac-address-in-android-6-0

Comment: 確認したのですが、Android6.0での事しか載っていないような気がします。

Comment: 一般のアプリについては、Android 6.0 以降は MAC アドレスは固定値となり、通常の方法では取得することはできません。Android for Work 向けのアプリケーションかつ Android 7.0 以降のみ例外があります。

Comment: android7.0の変更点でDevicePolicyManagerのgetWifiMacAddressで取得出来るとあったのですが

Comment: 前提条件に記載されている通り、Android for Work 向けのアプリケーションで、 Device Owner の権限を持つ場合には取得できるみたいですね。